# Asking for user input without input() python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

for my program i am using tkinter for the GUI. Before the program starts i want to have to input a password. I used the input() function. When running my code in my jupyter notebook everything works fine. So i created and executable file with pyinstaller, but when double clicking it won´t start and ask for the input. Since i often used pyinstaller i don´t think i failed in creating the exe-file, so my guess is, that the problem lies within the input() function. Is there another way to ask for user input?

I tried creating a window with an entry widget via Toplevel but i am not quite sure how to implement it since i want to start the program AFTER i entered the password.

My relevant code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    asd = input("Enter the password:")
    if asd == str(12345):
        app = GUI(master=root)
        app.master.title("Programm Links")
        app.master.minsize(600,400)
        root.config(menu=app.menubar)
        app.center(root)
        app.mainloop()
    else:
        root.destroy()
```

Comment: Using a tkinter dialog box?

Comment: well i didn´t know about that, i just used simpledialog.askstring and it works, though it not only shows the dialogbox but also a window frame. Meaning there are two windows when running the programm, though the second converts to the program i am calling upon entering the correct password

Comment: Better move the `root = tkinter.Tk()` into the if block and remove the else block.

Comment: if i do so, i get the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_viewable'.

Comment: ok i got it. I leave root = tkinter.Tk() outside the if block and put root.withdraw() afterwards, this hides the second unwanted window and only shows the dialogbox.

Answer (score 2):

So with help of the comments on my question i got an answer:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import simpledialog

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    asd = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password","Enter the password:")
    if asd == str(12345):
        app = GUI(master=root)
        app.master.title("Programm Links")
        app.master.minsize(600,400)
        root.config(menu=app.menubar)
        app.center(root)
        app.mainloop()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("WRONG PASSWORD","You entered a wrong password")
        root.destroy()
```

This creates a dialogbox that asks for a user input. root.withdraw() hides the root window frame that gets created by root = tkinter.Tk() which is needed for the dialogbox to run.

Comment: Did you forget to call `root.deiconify()` to restore the root window if password is ok?

Comment: i didn´t add it, though the result was what i wanted. Can u elaborate where and why you would add this ?

Comment: Because you use `root.withdraw()` to hide the root window before asking for password.  Then if the password is ok, you should unhide the root window.   In your case, I think the moving the root window to center by `app.center(root)` unhide the root window.

Comment: Ah yes, now that you mention it, my centering method does actually unhide the window with the deiconify() method. Thanks alot for pointing that out!